# Program stuck in nested switch

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Coffee Machine, however my program doesn't go back to the first switch loop after inputting something.

I have not encountered any error messages, and have tried to add break; statements.

All I need this program to do is return to the main switch loop so the user can keep using the program, instead of being stuck inside the second switch loop.

```
package machine;

import javax.crypto.spec.PSource;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int waterAmount = 400;
        int milkAmount = 540;
        int beanAmount = 120;
        int cupAmount = 9;
        int moneyAmount = 550;

        int fillWater = 0;
        int fillMilk = 0;
        int fillBeans = 0;
        int fillCups = 0;

        int takeCase = 0;

        boolean exitBoolean = false;


        String actionList = "Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):";
        String machineHas = "The coffee machine has:";
        String writeWater = "Write how many ml of water do you want to add:";
        String writeMilk = "Write how many ml of milk do you want to add: ";
        String writeBeans = "Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add:";
        String writeCups = "Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add:";
        String action1;
        String action2;

        System.out.println(machineHas);
        System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
        System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
        System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
        System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "of disposable cups");
        System.out.println(moneyAmount + " " + "of money");

        System.out.printf(actionList);
        action1 = s.next();

        while (!exitBoolean) {
            switch (action1) {
                case "buy":
                    System.out.printf("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino:");
                    action2 = s.next();
                    switch (action2) {
                        case "3":
                            waterAmount = waterAmount - 200;
                            milkAmount = milkAmount - 100;
                            beanAmount = beanAmount - 12;
                            cupAmount = cupAmount - 1;
                            moneyAmount = moneyAmount + 6;

                            System.out.println(machineHas);
                            System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
                            System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
                            System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
                            System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "of disposable cups");
                            System.out.println(moneyAmount + " " + "of money");
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            waterAmount = waterAmount - 350;
                            milkAmount = milkAmount - 75;
                            beanAmount = beanAmount - 20;
                            cupAmount = cupAmount - 1;
                            moneyAmount = moneyAmount + 7;

                            System.out.println(machineHas);
                            System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
                            System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
                            System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
                            System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "of disposable cups");
                            System.out.println(moneyAmount + " " + "of money");
                            break;
                        case "1":
                            waterAmount = waterAmount - 250;
                            beanAmount = beanAmount - 16;
                            cupAmount = cupAmount - 1;
                            moneyAmount = moneyAmount + 4;

                            System.out.println(machineHas);
                            System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
                            System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
                            System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
                            System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "of disposable cups");
                            System.out.println(moneyAmount + " " + "of money");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "fill":
                    System.out.println(writeWater);
                    fillWater = s.nextInt();

                    System.out.println(writeMilk);
                    fillMilk = s.nextInt();

                    System.out.println(writeBeans);
                    fillBeans = s.nextInt();

                    System.out.println(writeCups);
                    fillCups = s.nextInt();

                    waterAmount = waterAmount + fillWater;
                    milkAmount = milkAmount + fillMilk;
                    beanAmount = beanAmount + fillBeans;
                    cupAmount = cupAmount + fillCups;
                    moneyAmount = moneyAmount;

                    System.out.println(machineHas);
                    System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
                    System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
                    System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
                    System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "of disposable cups");
                    System.out.println(moneyAmount + " " + "of money");

                case "take":
                    System.out.println("I gave you $" + moneyAmount);

                    moneyAmount = moneyAmount - moneyAmount;

                    System.out.println(machineHas);
                    System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
                    System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
                    System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
                    System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "disposable cups");
                    System.out.println(moneyAmount + " of money");


                case "remaining":
                    System.out.println(machineHas);
                    System.out.println(waterAmount + " " + "of water");
                    System.out.println(milkAmount + " " + "of milk");
                    System.out.println(beanAmount + " " + "of coffee beans");
                    System.out.println(cupAmount + " " + "disposable cups");
                    System.out.println(moneyAmount + " of money");
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown Input!");
                case "exit":
                    exitBoolean = true;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use 'continue' inside a switch statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521721/why-cant-i-use-continue-inside-a-switch-statement-in-java)

Comment: Take a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521721/why-cant-i-use-continue-inside-a-switch-statement-in-java

Comment: Hey William, 

Thanks for giving me that question, however that didn't solve my problem. Perhaps I should be a bit more clearer in my question? 

I just need the nested switch loop to go back into the main switch loop.

Comment: Get rid of the continues, use break statements and retest

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, this still keeps the program stuck in the nested Switch. 

EDIT: I don't think this is a duplicate question as the other is asking about continue statements, whereas mine is stuck in a nested switch.

Comment: You've edited your question but have shown **no code** that gets rid of the continue statements and uses break statements correctly. -1

Comment: Also, you have `case "exit"` *after the `default` statement

Comment: @micgd move the part: ```System.out.printf(actionList);
   action1 = s.next();``` inside if the while loop and use **break** instead of **continue**.

Comment: @WilliamAndrésBernal thanks, it works now. Mark it as solved

Comment: There is no such thing as a switch-loop; a switch is sequential code that is a compact way of expressing certain kinds of if-then-else statements. Your nested switch statements are embedded in a while-loop, however.